# Change the size of homepage

Tags: layout, theme, home

I’m currently using this theme (http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/) on my website. Although this theme is great and better, comes for free I still have the complaint for with its Horizontal size. It’s too large to fit in screen. I don’t think that Customers actually like scrolling the page searching for things they want. I want the website to fit in the page. Being an amateur in PHP, I really don’t have any idea how can do it. I know if the length is changed then I’ll have to change the size of images too, but isn’t this possible that the images get resized automatically? Anyways, if that’s too hard to incorporate then anyone can please help me in at least making my website page fit in the screen horizontally? I’m good with vertical size, that is scrollable and the customers wouldn’t mind in scrolling through width. So, in short I want help in following:

1) Making the website fit in customer’s screen as per their browsers setting & resolution, automatically.
IF automatic accommodation of page is not possible, then

2) Help with the code to at least make the website fit in full, horizontally so that customers do not have to scroll for horizontal view. If you’re gonna suggest me a code change then it’s my folded hand request to please provide the code as well and the directory path where I should make the change. I’m a child in the world of coding and Magento so I don’t know anything. All I know is, I have to complete my website anyhow!
Please help me out and I’ll buy you a beer :)

---

Well I read somewhere that I need to make amendments in styles.css file. I opened it and seconds after I lying on the floor knocking my head. There's hell lot of codes which is almost an alien language for an amateur like me. Here is the Styles.css file of my homepage. Can anyone please tell what exactly should I modify? http://www.dirtrades.com/styles.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

> /skin/frontend/default/pagayo-theme-001/css/styles.css

`Find "width:1200px" -> Replace "width:1000px"`

Comment: Thanks for your effort and reply @Rahul, but it didn't help me. It's just pushing the images. I want to change the width of the page without disturbing the position of the images. The image next to the slider moved the and so did the third image on the bottom. Any help? Here is the screenshot of the page when I modified it as per your instructions- http://i59.tinypic.com/9u1cbb.png

Comment: Sorry Mohit, my answer didn't help you! I have re-checked your site! The main window width is set to 1200px, http://i59.tinypic.com/6en0id.jpg, but if you resize it the the other widths (like images and other layouts) get collapsed, And to change according the need of yours, it's not possible to solve this here in stack-exchange, please contact a front-end developer regarding this!

Comment: Oh, Alright. That isn't any good news for me. I'm a student I can't afford a big fat developer's fee. Stack-exchange was my only hope which seems to be shattering. Thanks anyway @Rahul.

Comment: Okay! Don't worry! Try to get some knowledge on CSS and you'll be good to go with your issue! Best Wishes

Answer (score 0):

Find the file:

app/design/frontend/**[YOUR_VENDOR]**/**[YOUR_THEME]**/web/css/_theme.less

In this file find the variable "**@ layout__max-width**" and edit the value.

As the documentation shows:

[image]

Por exemplo:

[image]

Now just compile the theme   **:)**